# What rights do I have on my biological brother and his wife and what rights do they have upon me?

Tags: family, human-rights

I am a 28 years old woman, and by the grace of Allah, alhamdoliAllah, I earn myself and I am not dependent on any person in family monetarily.

My question is that in islam, what rights do my brother, his wife and their children have upon me, and what rights do I have upon them?

---

EDIT: What I mean by *rights* is that every human has a duty towards another, for example a daughter has certain duties towards her mother, and those become the rights of the mother upon the daughter. So, I mean human rights.

---

**EDIT: This is what I mean by *rights:***

Like my mother has a right upon me that I address her with utmost respect. And I do "ehsaan" on her as instructed in Quran in 4:33. And I can never say anything harsh to her. And if I am rude to her, then God forbid one has to face the wrath of Allah.

Likewise, if she grows old and can not earn, then I have to support her financially. I have to give her medicines. I have to take her to the doctor. **All these are her rights and my farz/duty.**

So we know what rights parents have on their children. But my question is that what rights do siblings have on each other. What is my brother's farz towards me and what is mine towards him? Likewise what is the farz of my brother's wife towards me and vice versa. What is my farz towards borther's babies?

---

Comment: You should specify what you mean by rights in this context.